# Need help returning numbers on a seperate line

Tags: python

I am new to learning python. I am currently working on a problem on how to return how many eggs will fit into a carton (1 carton == a dozen eggs) and how many will be left over all based on a certain input. The challenge wants me to print the amount of cartons on one line and how many eggs left over on another.

For example:

If the input is 25, the program should print:

```
2

1
```

I am getting the right output, its just that I am having trouble outputting it like the challenge wants me to.

Basically, I created a function that does the calculations and then returns the outputs. The code is as follows.

```
    eggs = int(input())

    def dozen(x):
       y = x // 12
       z = x % 12
       return y, z

    a = dozen(eggs)

    print(a)
```

The output I recieve on the input of 25 is:

```
(2, 1)
```

But as mentioned before, I need it to be:

```
2

1
```

I appreciate any help given. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can index the tuple to print it separately:

```
print(a[0])
print(a[1])
```

Or, unpack the tuple and set the `sep` to `'\n'`:

```
print(*a, sep='\n')
```

Or (another option!), unpack the tuple earlier:

```
a, b = dozen(25)
print(a)
print(b)
```

You can also make your code better by using `divmod` like so:

```
def dozen(x):
   return divmod(x, 12)
```

Because integer division and modulo are essentially the same operation, it can be done in one go.

Comment: Okay, I have tried it, and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can do any of the following:

```
print(*a, sep='\n') #  unpack the values of and print them separated by a newline
```

or

```
a, b = dozen(eggs)  # unpack the return values and assign each of them to a and b respectively
print(a, b, sep='\n')
```

Incidentally, the `divmod` builtin will just give you the correct result from the get-go.

```
divmod(25, 12) #  returns 2, 1
```

Comment: Careful with `.join`; it expects strings.

Comment: Okay, I have tried it, and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Tomothy32, I always forget that.

Answer (score 0):

```py
eggs = int(input())

def dozen(x):
    y = x // 12
    z = x % 12
    print(y)
    print(z)
a = dozen(eggs)
```

why not just add the print statements to the function and lose the return.